# What is a RegEx to find phone numbers in Python?

Tags: python, regex, phone-number

I am trying to make a regex in python to detect 7-digit numbers and update contacts from a .vcf file. It then modifies the number to 8-digit number (just adding 5 before the number).Thing is the regex does not work.

I am having as error message "EOL while scanning string literal"

```
regex=re.compile(r'^(25|29|42[1-3]|42[8-9]|44|47[1-9]|49|7[0-9]|82|85|86|871|87[5-8]|9[0-8])/I s/^/5/')

#Open file for scanning
f = open("sample.vcf")

#scan each line in file
for line in f:
    #find all results corresponding to regex and store in pattern
    pattern=regex.findall(line)
#isolate results
    for word in pattern:
        print word
        count = count+1 #display number of occurences
        wordprefix = '5{}'.format(word)
        s=open("sample.vcf").read()
        s=s.replace(word,wordprefix)
        f=open("sample.vcf",'w')
        print wordprefix
        f.write(s)
        f.close()
```

I am suspecting that my regex is not in the correct format for detecting a particular pattern of numbers with 2 digits which have a particular format like the 25x and 29x and 5 digits that can be any pattern of numbers.. (TOTAL 7 digits)

can anyone help me out on the correct format to adopt for such a case?

Comment: Why does the regex look like that. Why not simply `[0-9]{7}` which finds all 7 digit numbers in the line ?

Answer (score 1):

`/I` is not how you give modifiers for regex in python. And neither you do substitution like `s///`.

You should use `re.sub()` for substitution, and give the modifier as `re.I`, as 2nd argument to `re.compile`:

```
reg = re.compile(regexPattern, re.I)
```

And then for a string `s`, the substitution would look like:

```
re.sub(reg, replacement, s)
```

---

As such, your regex looks weird to me. If you want to match 7 digits numbers, starting with `25` or `29`, then you should use:

```
r'(2[59][0-9]{5})'
```

And for replacement, use `"5\1"`. In all, for a string `s`, your code would look like:

```
reg = re.compile(r'(2[59][0-9]{5})', re.I)
new_s = re.sub(reg, "5\1", s)
```

Comment: +1 for not just answering the EOL but also fixing his scary long regex.

Comment: hey thanks.will try it later. Its long for a reason, because only certain pattern of numbers need to be changed there are also numbers starting with 421 422 and 423 etc... well all that are listed in the regex

Comment: @scandalous Sure, you can try it. Also, if you can give the exact requirement, we can help you create a shorter regex pattern.